# Does nginx send POST data to @fallback

Tags: nginx, http-proxy

I have nginx 1.2.7 with next configuration:

```
upstream backend_kes {
        ip_hash;
        server 127.0.0.1:9140 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=3s;
}

....

        location = /file/add {
                keepalive_timeout 0;

                set $upload_progress_fallback_code       360;
                set $upload_progress_memcached_servers   "127.0.0.2:11211";
                set $upload_progress_memcached_namespace setup-team.net;
                set $upload_progress_memcached_compress_threshold 10000;

                error_page 360 = @root2;
                perl My::handle;
        }
        location @root2 {
                proxy_pass http://backend_kes;
        }
```

This handler handle file uploading. All works fine for big files but small files are not saved. tcpdump shows next:

```
08:58:02.470116 IP 127.0.0.1.48396 > 127.0.0.1.9140: Flags [S], seq 1692815180, win 32792, options [mss 16396,sackOK,TS val 3699243831 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c b47b 4000 4006 883e 7f00 0001  E..<.{@.@..>....
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 bd0c 23b4 64e6 4f4c 0000 0000  ......#.d.OL....
    0x0020:  a002 8018 fe30 0000 0204 400c 0402 080a  .....0....@.....
    0x0030:  dc7d fb37 0000 0000 0103 0307            .}.7........
08:58:02.470146 IP 127.0.0.1.9140 > 127.0.0.1.48396: Flags [S.], seq 2061404772, ack 1692815181, win 32768, options [mss 16396,sackOK,TS val 3699243831 ecr 3699243831,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 4006 3cba 7f00 0001  E..<..@.@.<.....
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 23b4 bd0c 7ade 8a64 64e6 4f4d  ....#...z..dd.OM
    0x0020:  a012 8000 fe30 0000 0204 400c 0402 080a  .....0....@.....
    0x0030:  dc7d fb37 dc7d fb37 0103 0307            .}.7.}.7....
08:58:02.470165 IP 127.0.0.1.48396 > 127.0.0.1.9140: Flags [.], ack 1, win 257, options [nop,nop,TS val 3699243831 ecr 3699243831], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 b47c 4000 4006 8845 7f00 0001  E..4.|@.@..E....
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 bd0c 23b4 64e6 4f4d 7ade 8a65  ......#.d.OMz..e
    0x0020:  8010 0101 fe28 0000 0101 080a dc7d fb37  .....(.......}.7
    0x0030:  dc7d fb37                                .}.7
08:58:02.471383 IP 127.0.0.1.48396 > 127.0.0.1.9140: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 257, options [nop,nop,TS val 3699243832 ecr 3699243831], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 b47d 4000 4006 8844 7f00 0001  E..4.}@.@..D....
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 bd0c 23b4 64e6 4f4d 7ade 8a65  ......#.d.OMz..e
    0x0020:  8011 0101 fe28 0000 0101 080a dc7d fb38  .....(.......}.8
    0x0030:  dc7d fb37                                .}.7
08:58:02.471603 IP 127.0.0.1.9140 > 127.0.0.1.48396: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 256, options [nop,nop,TS val 3699243832 ecr 3699243832], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 715d 4000 4006 cb64 7f00 0001  E..4q]@.@..d....
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 23b4 bd0c 7ade 8a65 64e6 4f4e  ....#...z..ed.ON
    0x0020:  8011 0100 fe28 0000 0101 080a dc7d fb38  .....(.......}.8
    0x0030:  dc7d fb38                                .}.8
08:58:02.471641 IP 127.0.0.1.48396 > 127.0.0.1.9140: Flags [.], ack 2, win 257, options [nop,nop,TS val 3699243832 ecr 3699243832], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 b47e 4000 4006 8843 7f00 0001  E..4.~@.@..C....
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 bd0c 23b4 64e6 4f4e 7ade 8a66  ......#.d.ONz..f
    0x0020:  8010 0101 fe28 0000 0101 080a dc7d fb38  .....(.......}.8
    0x0030:  dc7d fb38                                .}.8
```

As you can see each packet has `length 0`. For big files > 30kb (I do not check 1500bytes, 3000bytes) I see packet length.

Does this the bug of nginx and it does not send content for POST request body if it fits in memory (or maybe one network packet <1500b)?

By design I allways return fallback code from My::handler

In browser for such requests I see no response [image: empty response]
In apache logs I do not see POST requests

Answer (score 0):

There were error in handler logic. If there is no body in response we should send 204 status code and not 200.

If we send 200 for empty body nginx just close connection and browser shows nothing.

IMHO. This is confusing and seems ugly to see nothing in browser. but good status in nginx logs:

```
2016/06/08 22:38:49 [debug] 21440#0: *13 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.7
Date: Wed, 08 Jun 2016 19:38:49 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
```